# how to override the default association=(associate) method of belongs_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a module, where I defined a function like this:

```
module A
  def item=(item)
    ...
  end
end
```

Then I have a class which has a belongs_to association and include the module A:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    include A
    belongs_to :item
    ...
end
```

I want the User class to have my item=, but it seems that this way doesn't work.

Can anyone tell me how to override the default item= method?

Comment: Which version of rails? The recently released 3.2 version adds support for modularized associations so that this will work (http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2012/1/20/modularized-association-methods-in-rails-3-2)

Answer (score 1):

Move the `include A` statement after the `belongs_to :item`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
  include A
  ...
end
```

the `belongs_to :item` statement is redefining the `item=` method.